# How to multi-thread parallelizable tasks in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a method within a class that does some computation:

```
class ParticleSystem:
    int size;
    double weight;
    ArrayList<Particle> P;
    public void updatePosition(){
          work on LIST P;  // <---- can be done in parallel
    }
    public void updateVelocity(){
          work on LIST P;  // <---- can be done in parallel
    }

    public void updateFrame(){  // <---- Invoked for each frame
          updatePosition();
          updateVelocity();
    }

    public static void main(){
          while(true){
               updateFrame(); // <----- render to screen
          }
    }
}
```

So each updatePosition() and updateVelocity() call can be parallelized among the particles. So I would like to develop an efficient way of multi-threading these two tasks.

So after some research on java multi-threading, I found that I can implement a thread class that implements Runnable. By creating new threads every iteration and put those 2 methods into the run() method, I can execute these two tasks.
However, this way there is much overhead in creating threads (I have 4 core 8 thread processor, so I create 8 threads each iteration)
I read about Executors and ThreadPool objects. I am not very clear how to use them. If using them is a good idea, please help me by giving me some example usages! MUCH APPRECIATED!

EDIT 1:

```
class Particle:
    double x_position, y_position, z_position;
    double x_newPosition, y_newPosition, z_newPosition;
```

The aforementioned 2 tasks do not require synchronization, meaning that they take x_positions and update x_newPositions. After each task, though, all threads should join and then proceed to the next task.

Comment: Your question is very vague... Which data is shared ? What are the precedence constraints ?

Comment: Hi Dici, the parallel methods will only read data field 1 and write to data field 2, so no synchronization is needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use Executor Service with a Cached Thread Pool executor.
You would have to take care of threading issues, if any.
Sample Code is below.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updatePosition();
        }
    });

    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateVelocity();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please show me how to use it in the main method? Namely, how to invoke the execute methods. It seems that these two execute methods are in parallel.

Comment: This would look like normal sequential methods, one after the other, but would effectively end up getting executed in parallel, since the .execute method would not wait for the first one to complete before starting the second one. Code with Main method: http://ideone.com/ONHB4H

Comment: Oh sorry. Maybe I did not make it clear. I meant, updatePosition() for all particles need to be done before updateVelocity can start. So these two methods should be executed in series. But each of them can be run in parallel for all the elements in the ArrayList.

Comment: Then you could loop through your list, and start executing your updateFrame function for each of them in a parallel way using a similar executorService. Like in http://ideone.com/GxiJRA